# Upgrade log4j in Spring Boot with maven

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, log4j

I'm trying to upgrade log4j library in my spring boot projects :

**POM file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ipplan</groupId>
    <artifactId>ipplan</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<!--    <packaging>war</packaging>-->
    <name>ipplan-api</name>
    <description>ip plan</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
    </properties>
    
    
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>ipplan-api</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The issue is that maven downloads version 2.14.1 of log4j-bom :

[image]

Comment: Without the full pom file etc. it's impossible to say or even help...

Comment: i just added full pom file

Comment: You are mixing different spring boot/spring versions...

Comment: how can i get the spring library that uses log4j 2.14.1

Comment: Your parent uses version 2.5.1 while `spring-boot-starter-mail` uses 2.5.3... also the question is if theamleaf using spring4 is correct (I have my doubts)...

Comment: He should remove the thymeleaf dependencies and use the proper `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` instead. This will automatically use the correct thymeleaf version.

Comment: i removed spring-boot-starter-mail version, so the same version of the parent would be used, i also used spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf, but 2.14.1 still downloads

Comment: i also tried to comment all the dependencies, after running mvn install, 2.14.1 still downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using spring boot parent version 2.5.1 that is why it is downloading log4j 2.14.1 by default during the build. There are no other conflicts with any of the other dependencies in your pom.xml so try the latest spring boot starter-parent version.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```